# Remove and return adjacent elements from a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this: `[1, 3, 4, 5, 1]`
and I want to remove the first `n` elements, so for `n = 3`, I want to return that list, while removing it from the original list. So I'd have `[1,3,4]`
 and my original list is now `[5, 1]`.

What is the best way to do that in python?

Comment: That solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2.7 this would look like the following. Simply extract a partial list and delete the unneeded part in the original version.

```
lst = [1, 3, 4, 5, 1]
new_lst = lst[:3] 
del lst[:3]
print lst
print new_lst
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mutate the original object, you can change it using `[:]`.  For example:

```
>>> x = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> x[:], removed = x[3:], x[:3]
>>> x
['d', 'e']
>>> removed
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

This works because the terms on the right hand side, `x[3:]` and `x[:3]`, are both evaluated before they're assigned to the targets on the left (`x[:]` and `removed`).

Comment: I wouldn't bother with `x[:]`; assigning to `x` itself has the same result, and the delay in garbage-collecting the original list is unlikely to affect the overall performance of the program.

Comment: @chepner: it doesn't have the same result -- imagine that `x` were being passed into a function.  Using `x` on the left hand side would just rebind the local name `x`, it wouldn't modify the list.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```py
def pop_n(lst, n):
    """
    Deletes the first *n* elements from *lst* and returns them.
    """
    # validate inputs
    # might want to use something other than isinstance()
    if not isinstance(n, int) or n < 0:
        raise ValueError("n must be a non-negative integer, not {}"
                         .format(n))

    # store the elements to return
    ret = lst[:n]
    # remove the elements from the original list
    del lst[:n]

    return ret
```

EDIT: Here's a demonstration with your example case.

```py
>>> x = [1, 3, 4, 5, 1]

>>> pop_n(x, 3)
[1, 3, 4]
>>> x
[5, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> original = [1, 3, 4, 5, 1]
>>> removed, original[:3] = original[:3], ()
>>> removed, original
([1, 3, 4], [5, 1])
```